# Random text generator for wordpress or similar?

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple landing page in wordpress. I wish to display a random message (text strings). Users can click a button or refesh page to see new comment. The text is current stored in an excel csv file. Is there any simple plug in available or could this easily be coded for wordpress or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this plugin, and a regular input button to refresh the page, each page refresh should get you a new quote.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quotes-collection/other_notes/

in your page include:

[quotcol1 orderby="random" limit=1]

or you can use the quotescollection_quote() function that comes with it and have it auto-refresh, and show a random one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to replace my Chuck Norris author bio with a random Chuck Norris fact on load.  Plus, a link to reload the current page:

```
<?php if(get_the_author_meta('display_name') == 'Chuck Norris'){
$messages = array(
    'Chuck Norris doesn\'t read books. He stares them down until he gets the information he wants.',
    'Time waits for no man. Unless that man is Chuck Norris.',
    'If you spell Chuck Norris in Scrabble, you win. Forever.',
    'Chuck Norris breathes air ... five times a day.',
    'In the Beginning there was nothing ... then Chuck Norris roundhouse kicked nothing and told it to get a job.',
    'When God said, "Let there be light!" Chuck said, "Say Please."',
    'Chuck Norris has a mug of nails instead of coffee in the morning.',
    'If Chuck Norris were to travel to an alternate dimension in which there was another Chuck Norris and they both fought, they would both win.',
    'The dinosaurs looked at Chuck Norris the wrong way once. You know what happened to them.',
    'Chuck Norris\' tears cure cancer. Too bad he has never cried.',
    'Chuck Norris once roundhouse kicked someone so hard that his foot broke the speed of light',
);
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );

echo "<p>".$messages[rand(0, count($messages) - 1)]."<br><br><a href=\"".$current_url."#author\" style=\"text-decoration:underline;\">Click for another Chuck fact</a> -- if your ego can handle it!</p>";  
} else {
?>
                        <p><?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('description')); ?></p>
                <?php } ?>
```